# Prove that $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]=a+b\sqrt{2}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2-2)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, group-isomorphism

Prove that $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]= \{a+b\sqrt{2}:a,b\in\mathbb{Q}\}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2-2)$.

I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around this question and just need a little help starting it.

Specifically, I can't figure out what the function is for $\phi:\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]\rightarrow\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2-2)$, i.e. how $a+b\sqrt{2}$ maps to something.

Any help is welcome, thank you!

edit: I copied it wrong, they are isomorphic.

Comment: But it is.....?

Comment: (i) They *are* isomorphic. (ii) Generally speaking, when you want to define an isomorphism and one of the two objects is a quotient, it is easier to map from the quotient side, not *to* the quotient side. (iii) Defining a morphism with domain $A/B$ is usually best done by defining a morphism with domain $A$ and then showing that $B$ lies in the kernel, thus "automatically" giving you an induced map from $A/B$.

Comment: Hint: do you understand what elements in a quotient ring $R/I$, where $I$ is an ideal look like?

Comment: We can’t prove they are not isomorphic, because…

Comment: Or maybe you meant $\,\Bbb Q[x]/(x^2-\color{#c00}3),\,$ which is a common exercise and already answered here many times.

Answer (score 2):

You can prove that they are isomorphic, using the first isomorphism theorem, for rings. Consider the ring homomorphism $\phi:\mathbb{Q}[x] \to \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$ such that $\phi\left(\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^na_ix^i\right)=\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^na_i{\sqrt{2}}^i$ i.e the substitution map. Clearly, $\phi(a+bx)=a+b\sqrt{2}$ so, $\phi$ is surjective. The kernel is the set of rational polynomials which vanish at $\sqrt{2}$. Since $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ is a PID, and $x^2-2$ is a polynomial of lowest degree vanishing at $\sqrt{2}$, $\ker{\phi}=\langle x^2-2 \rangle$. Thus, $\mathbb{Q}[x]/\langle x^2-2 \rangle \cong \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$.