# Prove that $\mathbb{Q}[x]/\langle 3+3x+x^2\rangle \cong \mathbb{Q}(i\sqrt{3})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, ring-isomorphism

If $\mathbb{Q}(i\sqrt{3})=\left\{a+b(i\sqrt{3}) \:\vert\: a,b \in\mathbb{Q}\right\}$ then $\mathbb{Q}[x]/\langle 3+3x+x^2\rangle \cong \mathbb{Q}(i\sqrt{3})$. An earlier part of this problem asks to prove that if $\lambda$ is a root of a polynomial $a_0+b_0x+x^2$ then $\mathbb{Q}(\lambda=\left\{a+b\lambda)\:\vert\: a,b \in\mathbb{Q}\right\}$ is a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ and I've proved it. However, I'm not sure if it can help me solve this question.

Comment: Did you figure out the roots of $3+3x+x^2$?

Comment: Yes, they're $\lambda_1=-\frac{3}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ and $\lambda_2=-\frac{3}{2}-i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$. I also noticed that $\mathbb{Q}[\lambda_1]=\mathbb{Q}[\lambda_2]=\mathbb{Q}[i\sqrt{3}]$, so I only need to prove $\mathbb{Q}/\langle3+3x+x^2\rangle\cong \mathbb{Q}[\lambda_1]$ or $\mathbb{Q}[\lambda_2]$, which sounds more familiar.

Comment: Maybe the Fundamental Isomorphism Theorem will help.

Comment: [This link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4312719/prove-that-mathbbq-sqrt2-ab-sqrt2-is-isomorphic-to-mathbbqx-x) helps you; I think this is almost the same question.